# Why iPhone emulators display web page differently than real iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

There's a web page at http://examinemysite.com/foodRating. The webpage shows properly in two iPhone emulators as shown below. However testing using a real iPhone and a real WP7 phone, the size of the text and the stars are a lot smaller. Why are the physical devices not showing the same page like the emulators (same size text, stars and spacing)? The emulators are running under Windows 7.

**IBBDEMO**:

[image]

**MITE:**

[image]

Comment: I tried it on my simulator,its all working fine.
And I think iOS has got simulator,how did you make it emulator..:)

Comment: What is all working fine? Did you use an iPhone and an emulator? The name of the emulators are on top of the images.

Comment: Means the appearance of the web-page is appearing fine on simulator.

Comment: I know it shows fine on the emulator. I am saying it doesn't show fine on the phone.

Comment: Well, don't know about the others, but the Apple software is a simulator, not an emulator.  There's a reason for the distinction.

Comment: @Abdu you expect far too much from an emulator... to be as perfect as you expect the emulator must be implemented based on the real source used for iOS/iPhone which is fully available only to Apple.

Comment: @Hot Licks What Apple software? I am running in Windows.

Comment: @Yahia This is a web page, not a native app. The emulator is emulating a browser. It's showing everything, just not in the right resolution. So it already did all the webpage rendering which is all the work.

Comment: @Abdu even that you can't expect since the browser in iOS/iPhone is not 100% identical to whatever these emulators can do - it will differ in one way or another... to really test an app use the real device OR the simulator which comes from the phone's vendor. period.

Answer (score 1):

You're using tools that simply try to display what they think would be displayed by MobileSafari. IBBDEMO is, if I'm not mistaken, an Adobe Air application. I'm not sure about MITE, but I don't think it has any special knowledge of MobileSafari either. These tools seem like nothing more than web browsers that display in a small 320x480 window with an iPhone image wrapped around the display area. It would be fairly astonishing if they did a perfect job of simulating MobileSafari.

Comment: So why are these emulators showing 320x480 when a device like iPhone has double the resolution? Seems like they would be useless if they don't show what the device shows. In MITE I am choosing iPhone 4S.

Comment: The Apple iPhone 4 has a 320 x 480 screen resolution, with a device pixel ratio of 2, so the simulation is accurate - at least in terms of size.